# MySQL Nested SQL with limits

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, limit

I know it's not possible to use limits within nested INs, but I think there is a way to do this, I'm just not sure how.

I have a table that contains both ratings and comments (simplified for explanation)

```
mySingleTable: 
+----+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | reviewer_comment | is_rating | parent_id | reviewer_rating | 
+----+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+ 
| 1  | well done rateA  | 1         |  0        | 5 Stars         | 
| 2  | commentAonRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 |
| 3  | commentBonRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 | 
| 4  | commentConRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 |
| 5  | commentDonRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 | 
| 6  | commentEonRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 | 
| 7  | commentFonRateA  | 0         |  1        |                 | 
| 8  | well done rateB  | 1         |  0        | 4 Stars         | 
| 9  | well done rateC  | 1         |  0        | 5 Stars         | 
| 11 | well done rateD  | 1         |  0        | 3 Stars         | 
| 12 | well done rateE  | 1         |  0        | 2 Stars         |
| 13 | well done rateF  | 1         |  0        | 5 Stars         | 
| 14 | well done rateG  | 1         |  0        | 3 Stars         | 
| 15 | commentAonRateD  | 0         |  11       |                 | 
+----+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

So,
if is_rating = 1, its a rating.
if is_rating = 0, its a comment on the rating (its parent rating is where parent_id=id)

so this would look like:

```
well done rateA *****  
 commentAonRateA  
 commentBonRateA  
 commentConRateA  
 commentDonRateA  
 commentEonRateA  
 commentFonRateA    
well done rateB ****  
well done rateC *****  
well done rateD ***  
 commentAonRateD    
well done rateE **  
well done rateF *****  
well done rateG ***
```

What I want to do is select the newest five ratings, with the ASSOCIATED newest 5 comments, using only 1 query

So, some how join these two:

```
SELECT ratings.*
        FROM mySingleTable as ratings
        WHERE 
        is_rating = 1
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 5  

    SELECT comments.*
        FROM mySingleTable as comments
        Where 
        comments.parent_id = ratings.id 
        AND is_rating = 0
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

The 2nd query needs to somehow know about the ratings query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query which is now simplified and tested.

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT *,
        IF (group_id = @prev,
            @n := @n + 1,
            @n := 1 AND @prev := group_id) as position
 FROM (
   SELECT mySingleTable.*, group_id
   FROM   mySingleTable
   INNER JOIN
       (SELECT id AS group_id
        FROM   mySingleTable
        WHERE  is_rating = 1
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 5
       ) AS top5ratings
   ON     mySingleTable.id = group_id OR mySingleTable.parent_id = group_id
   ORDER BY group_id DESC,
            mySingleTable.parent_id ASC,
            timestamp DESC) AS all_reviews
  JOIN  (SELECT @n := 0, @prev := 0) AS setup) AS reviews
WHERE reviews.position < 7
```

Keep in mind that SELECT * is bad practice. I used it to simplify reading.

Comment: Spot on, that's fairly incredible and more complex that I was expecting.  Thanks Koriander

Comment: You are welcome! It's not pretty indeed, it's the result of forcing low-level programming in a high-level language...

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS QUERY

```
SELECT comments.*
FROM
(
SELECT ratings.id
        FROM mySingleTable as ratings
        WHERE 
        is_rating = 1
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ) AS Top5
INNER JOIN mySingleTable AS comments ON  comments.parent_id = Top5.id 
WHERE comments.is_rating = 0
ORDER BY comments.timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Using that Query on my data sample, I get 4 ratings and 1 comment on one of the ratings.  I should always be getting 5 ratings (and a limit of up to 5 comments on each rating).  I'm trying to work out why now

Comment: -- It's not quite there.  That final limit will be a limit on the entire returned data, so this query will never return more than 5 rows. But in theory it should be possible to return the 1st rating with its latest 5 comments and the subsequent 4 ratings (with their related 5 recent comments, if they have comments)

Comment: create tables and insert this data then join <WITH> CLAUSE doesn't support MySQL

Comment: yeah, temp tables is an an oracle solution, this is MySQL Data, so sadly I can't use that trick